# Unable to fetch ZONE from the Cloud Shell instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

I want to get the zone where the Cloud Shell VM instance resides, I created this custom script to fetch the zone via the metadata server; however it's not working. What can I be missing (I know that if I were to do this from a normal VM instance I would have to enable API access to the metadata server)

```
#! /bin/bash
ZONE=$(curl -s http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/ -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
echo $ZONE
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the Zone where your Cloud Shell is in you can run the following command:

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone
```

You may want to use this as a reference for your script or use it directly as presented.